# How to pass a jquery variable to html while calling post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am completely new to `HTML` and `jquery`, I have calculated some value in `jquery` part and that variable I want to pass to `HTML`.

```
<script>
    var datetime = new Date();
    var res = datetime.toString(); //res is the variable
</script> // end of the string

<div class="col-xs-8 center login-sub-container clearfix">
    <form id="loginDetails" name="loginDetails" action="http://192.198.9.228/loginOnline" method="post">
        <div class="login-form-elements">
            <input type="hidden" value=res name="dateTime"> // here the result i want to pass
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

When I see request packet I am seeing like the value is passing `result` not the value is inside the result variable

Comment: `jQuery("input[name=dateTime]").val(res)`  also remove value=result

Comment: You could not pass the value to the HTML. but you can set the value to element like $("ínput").val(result);

Answer (score 2):

jQuery is unnecessary here. Just use [`.value`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_value.asp)

Also do not set attribute in html without single or double quotes.
I mean that part `<input ... value=res ...>` You should always use single `'` or double `"` quotes (`<input ... value="res" ...>`)

```js
var datetime = new Date();
var res = datetime.toString();

document.querySelector("input[name='dateTime']").value = res;
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-8 center login-sub-container clearfix">
  <form id="loginDetails" name="loginDetails" action="http://192.198.9.228/loginOnline" method="post">
    <div class="login-form-elements">
      <input type="text" value="result" name="dateTime">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah.. I saw your answer and upvoted it, I guess the right thing was to delete my answer. I had added an `id` to get the element. Then used the querySelector which turned out you had already used.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jQuery.val](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```js
var datetime = new Date();
var res = datetime.toString();
$("[name='dateTime']").val(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-xs-8 center login-sub-container clearfix">
                        <form id="loginDetails" name="loginDetails" action="http://192.198.9.228/loginOnline" method="post">
                            <div class="login-form-elements">
 <input type="hidden" value=result name="dateTime" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set the value.

For example, with JQuery:

$("[name=dateTime]").val(res);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, you achieve this as mentioned below :

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script>
    var datetime = new Date();
    var res = datetime.toString(); //res is the variable
     $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#datetime").val(res);
    });
</script> // end of the string
```

Then in the hidden text just add an id like :

```
<input type="hidden" name="dateTime" id="datetime" >
```

Then here it is not necessary to provide a seperate value attribute. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to offer a different solution as I feel you want to submit this form along with current date time field. This is how you can set dynamic value before you submit a form in jQuery.

```
<script>
var datetime = new Date();
var res = datetime.toString(); //res is the variable
function submitForm(){
    $("#loginDetails input[name=dateTime]").val(res);
    console.log($("#loginDetails input[name=dateTime]").val());
    $("#loginDetails").submit();
}   
</script>

<div class="col-xs-8 center login-sub-container clearfix">
    <form id="loginDetails" name="loginDetails" action="http://192.198.9.228/loginOnline" method="post">
        <div class="login-form-elements">
            <input type="hidden" value=res name="dateTime"> // here the result i want to pass
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm();">
    </form>
</div>
```